# i have my image in a local folder. I have its path in my database which i am able to access. how do I sent the image to a html page?

Tags: javascript, css, html, python-3.x

I have my image in a local folder on my system. I have its file-path in my mysql database which I am able to access in my code. How do I send the image to an HTML page from within my code(I use python/Flask)?

Comment: You need to set the upload folder of your flask app, and fetch the url of the image from the database. To send direct access to your image, you need to create a route and send the image file directly. But are you able to set the upload folder of your flask app?